# How to check if Data is correctly posted to webservice in android?

Tags: android

I want to check if I have successfully posted the data to webservice using the httppost method. How to verify that the data is posted successfully?
How to check if json.put("URL".getpref()); is successfully posted to webservice?

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url1);
try {
json.put("URL", getPref());


Log.i("json Object", json.toString());
StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(json.toString());

stringEntity.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
stringEntity.setContentType("application/json");
post.setEntity(stringEntity);
//ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
response = client.execute(post);
Log.e("RESPONSE", response.toString());
String responseBody = EntityUtils
toString(response.getEntity());
System.out.println(responseBody);
```

Comment: have you implemented the code or not?

Comment: yes... i just want to check if it is correctly posted to webservice or not?

Comment: Ok... i have posted answer check it and compare with your code..

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the response from the server. The response from a webservice could be as simple as a string like `"success"`. If you or your team has access to the webservice you may ask to them to return appropriate repsonse from the server.